# Trying to create a navigation menu with links to each <h2> title on a page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to create a navigation menu using jQuery with links to each `<h2>` title on pages created and published in Wordpress. Some of these pages can get a bit lengthy so this navigation menu should make it quick and easy for visitors to jump to certain parts of it's content.

I've got it set up so that each `<h2>` title creates it's own unique ID by using it's content prefixed by **"#"** (i.e. **"My title"** would get the ID **"#My title"**) using this piece of code below:

```
jQuery("h2").each(function(){
      var id = jQuery(this).html();
      jQuery(this).attr("id", "#" + id);
})
```

Basically step 1 of 10.. What's left is to create a function that loops trough each `<h2>` that exists on the page and then creates a menu item for each of those titles. I kind of understand javascript loops but I'm just not sure how to get this to actually create new elements like this.

I'm still a novice when it comes down to Javascript or even jQuery so I apologise if anything's unclear.

Anyways I hope somebody can point me in the right direction. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Using `jQuery(this).html()` in this way is a bad idea. At an absolute minimum, you should use `.text()`, as you don't want the HTML contents of the `<h2>`, you want the text. However, even then, you need to sanitize it such that it only contains characters which are valid in an `id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, I'm guessing that you are trying to create a navigation menu at the top of the page where it creates links to each of your `<h2>` subheadings.

I don't really know how wordpress works but here are some ways that it can be achieved in jquery:

You should store your `<h2>` elements in an array. You can do this by adding the id as you make them. You don't need a loop for this! (Also, if I were you, I wouldn't add the # before the ID, because then you would have to write "##name" when you try to call the ID in javascript or css.)

```
var arr = [];
$("h2").each(function(){
    var id = $(this).html();
    $(this).attr("id", id);
    arr.push($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Now that you have the data for your `<h2>` elements, you can just loop through it to create your list. First, just create an empty `<ul id="nav"></ul>` in javascript. Then, you can keep adding `<li></li>` in it with the h2 contents. To add the links, you just have to surround the text with an `<a href='#name'></a>`.

So it would turn out to be something like this:

```
for (i in arr) {
  $('ul#nav').append('<li><a href="#' + arr[i] + '">' + arr[i] + '</a></li>');
}
```

You can of course then make the css to style the unordered list, and it can serve as a nav.
I hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you Natsu for such a clear explanation, it works! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot you really helped me out here.